# Screen Time and Limits stopped working

Tags: settings, pantheon, time

I installed elementary os just a few days ago primarily to use the Screen Time and Limits function, to improve my own sleep hygiene.  I got Screen Time and Limits to auto log-off/shutdown at bedtime the 1st night.

On the 2nd night when it didn't work I tried toggling my account, weekdays, and weekend sections on and off, as well as adjusting the times, but to no avail.

Googling the issue led me to a few very old articles that were no longer relevant and I couldn't find it listed either, I was hoping I could uninstall and reinstall it (using the command:  apt list --installed).  I feel like the issue is having to do with something very basic, an oversight on my end perhaps.

- using the latest version of elementary os
- am only using the "screen time" section of Screen Time & Limits
- I'm the only one using the pc
- have been using linux for ca. 6 months, know just the basics

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and used your suggestion abrattic and it worked. Thank you for your help.

Comment: please mark my answer as accepted by clicking the green tick mark.

Comment: hi cytosage, you marked the wrong answer as the correct one. It would be great if you could mark @abrattic's answer instead :)

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a different account as an administrator and change your current account to a standard account. This feature is basically supposed to be for kids with standard(non-administrator) accounts so this may fix it.